# How to pass projects as parameter while using dotnet publish command in DotNetCoreCLI@2 task

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have dotnet core project and using 'DotNetCoreCLI@2' task in Azure Pipeline to publish the code. My 'DotNetCoreCLI@2' task looks like this:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Dotnet Publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: |
      **/*.csproj
      !**/*Blazor.csproj
    arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

This works when used. Now I am trying to build template and want to pass projects values as variables or parameters but failing to do so.
Here is what I tried (I am using variable here)

```
variables:  
  projectsToPublish: '**/*.csproj;!**/*Blazor.csproj'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Dotnet Publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: $(projectsToPublish)
    arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

I also tried using variables like this, but it didn't work and keep getting this error message: *##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.*

```
variables:
  projectsToPublish:  '|
      **/*.csproj
      !**/*Blazor.csproj'
or
variables:
  projectsToPublish:  '**/*.csproj
                    !**/*Blazor.csproj'
```

Any idea how I can set projects values in variables and use it in publish task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can set projects values in variables and use it in publish task?

To solve this issue, you can define multiple line variable in Azure YAML Pipeline.

For example:

```
variables:
  projectsToPublish: | 
     **/*.csproj
     !**/*Blazor.csproj
   
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: echo "$(projectsToPublish)"

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: |
      $(projectsToPublish)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I cannot get this to work if I specify full paths to my 2 projects I want to publish:       variables projectsToPublish: | 
        $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Source/WebAPI.csproj
        $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Source/Events.csproj

##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

Comment: However this seems to work:   variables projectsToPublish: | 
        **/*WebAPI.csproj
        **/*Events.csproj

Comment: @OliverNilsen if you find better answer, you can add new answer to share your solution instead of downvote this answer. This sample should work in the situation of the original question.

Comment: Sorry I clicked on the DownArrow by mistake. I actually wanted to UpVote it but now it is locked for 18 hours. Will definitely upvote.

Comment: @OliverNilsen Okay. Never Mind.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script) for a try.
Firstly, ensure in your repo the '**/*.csproj;!**/*Blazor.csproj' files do exist.
Then you could try this:

```
parameters:  
- name: projectsToPublish
  type: string
  values:
  - '**/*.csproj'
  - '!**/*Blazor.csproj'
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Dotnet Publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: ${{ parameters.projectsToPublish}}
    arguments: '-o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

For parameters execute in runtime, you will need to choose the value after click run:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Choose one then click 'run', then you are supposed to run the task.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uoPk.png

Comment: I get an error when I do this:  projectsToPublish: | 
        $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Source\**\Web.API.csproj
        $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Source\**\Events.csproj

Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.
Is it because variables cannot resolve another variable